# Retrieving the data in every request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to retrieve the data from cookie in every request in ASP.NET MVC and store it in a global variable so that it'll be available throughout the application.

I've two questions here is there any event-handler in ASP.NET MVC where I can get the data from cookie in every request and what kind of global variable I can use to store this cookie value so it is available in all places?

Comment: Unless this application is only ever used by the same one person, I doubt you want to store a users cookie value in a global variable.  Why not just use session state?

Comment: @UpTheCreek I agree with you. The global variable I meant here is not global to all users but it can be accessible anywhere in the MVC app for the particular user.. I can use session but if the data is lost from cookie still the data will float in session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter to get the cookie in every request. Create for example a class `MyFilter`

```
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];

        //do something with cookie.Value
        if (cookie!=null) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["myCookieValue"] = cookie.Value;
        // or put it in a static class dictionary ...
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Mark every controller class with `[MyFilter]` attribute.
This example takes the cookie and puts the value in the session so it's available in all the views and all the controllers. Else you can put the cookie value in a static class that contains a static `Dictionary` and use the session ID as key. There are many way to store the cookie value and access it in every part of the application.

Comment: or register it as a global filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attributes on each request or make a custom Controller and handle "OnActionExecuting" (override)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can use Attributes? I like the second option.

Answer (score 0):

You could go old school and handle the onrequest event in the asax file. That way you could abstract the code out to an httpmodule if you need to reuse the approach in another app. The filters approach is probably better though.