# Solving cookie replay attack in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms, forms-authentication

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31566035/4451931) answer on StackOverflow, Microsoft has suggested to do the following actions:

1. Clear the cookie.
2. Set the Response.Status property to 401.
3. Make a call to the Response.End method that will implicitly redirect
   the to the logon page.

I came up with this line of code in my `global.asax` file, (I have added an extra field to my user table named `isLogin` which I set to true and false in Login and Logout pages ...)

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPrincipal p = HttpContext.Current.User;

            if (p.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userName = p.Identity.Name;
                HttpCookie authenticationCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

                if (SecurityUtilities.CheckUserLoggedIn(userName) == false)
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    Response.End();
                }              
            }
        }
```

I am wondering am I doing all this correct? What about this code?

```
if (SecurityUtilities.CheckUserLoggedIn(userName) == false)
{  

 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
}
```